# Google Sheets formula recalculation catch

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

**Context:**

I import data into my `Data` sheet using a custom `ImportJSON` function.
To be able to manipulate this data, I refer to it from another `Dashboard` sheet like so `=INDEX(Data!E:E, $A2)` (there are many columns, some of them refer to the raw data, others make some calculations based on a raw data).
Finally, I have a custom function for sending notifications based on some criteria. It takes the number of matching rows e.g. `=handleNotification(COUNTIF(...))`.
However, during the data update, the number of matching rows will change (thus triggering false-positive notification on every data update).
To prevent this, I added a helper cell `=ISERROR(Data!A1)` which indicates whether the data is being imported. And then the cell that counts the number of matching rows is `=IF(<Ref ISERROR cell>, <Ref itself>, COUNTIF(...))`. This way, the formula is recalculated only when the data update is finished and returns a valid number continuously at any time.

**It works perfectly! BUT**

I can't achieve the same behavior when I want to count the number of matching rows from the `Dashboard` (indexed cells) instead of `Data` (raw array data). This means during the data update the value of the formula becomes `0` for a moment, and only after the data update is finished it returns the correct number. It causes false-positive triggering of the `handleNotification` function and generates wrong notifications every time.

**Is there a similar way to make the formula recalculate only after all rows are updated?**
So it returns a valid number continuously, not `54 -> 0 (for a split second during the data update) -> 56` as I did with the `ISERROR` helper cell for raw data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **haven't found a way** to use the data from the `Dashboard` sheet directly as I wanted to, but found some **workaround that works**.

So to count matching rows I use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N((Data!U:U = "foo") * (Data!E:E * 5 > 20))))
```

instead of the `COUNTIF` function which doesn't allow performing calculations, only simple logical checks.

Then I wrap it around like I did before:

```
=IF(<Ref ISERROR cell>, <Ref itself>, ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N((Data!U:U = "foo") * (Data!E:E * 5 > 20)))))
```

**It doesn't return wrong values during the data update and allows me to include any calculations as a condition.** But the downside of this approach is you have to compute everything once again, which otherwise you could just take from the `Dashboard` sheet directly.

I will stick with this solution unless I find a better one.